# create cte multiple times and drop cte

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, common-table-expression

I am using a cte in stored procedure.

I have to use it multiple times ie populate cte for different ids

how can I drop or remove current cte

thanks

```
;WITH PAYOUT_CTE(REGNKEY, REGNTPE) AS (
    SELECT  REG_KEY, 'Parent'
    FROM    ML_MSTR_REGN A (NOLOCK)
    WHERE   A.COMP_NO = @COMP_NO
        AND     A.REG_KEY = @CUR_KEY

    UNION   ALL

    SELECT  B.REG_KEY, 'Child0'
    FROM    PAYOUT_CTE
    INNER JOIN ML_MSTR_REGN B
        ON  B.COMP_NO = @COMP_NO
           AND  B.ORG_KEY = PAYOUT_CTE.REGNKEY
            )
SELECT * INTO #PAYOUT_CTE_TMP FROM PAYOUT_CTE
```

I resolved it, as cte is automatically removed after the insert statement
only the temp table #PAYOUT_CTE_TMP was causing the problem.

Comment: My understanding is that a CTE just gets inlined to regular SQL code, and it only exists for a single statement.  After the statement is over, you may define another CTE with the same name.  Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can see this working is if you put the CTE code in a inline table valued function and call that.

Your code would look something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION TVFN_PAYOUT_CTE (@COMP_NO INT, @CUR_KEY INT) 
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (

WITH PAYOUT_CTE(REGNKEY, REGNTPE) AS (
    SELECT  REG_KEY, 'Parent'
    FROM    ML_MSTR_REGN A (NOLOCK)
    WHERE   A.COMP_NO = @COMP_NO
        AND     A.REG_KEY = @CUR_KEY

    UNION   ALL

    SELECT  B.REG_KEY, 'Child0'
    FROM    PAYOUT_CTE
    INNER JOIN ML_MSTR_REGN B
        ON  B.COMP_NO = @COMP_NO
           AND  B.ORG_KEY = PAYOUT_CTE.REGNKEY
            )
SELECT * 
FROM PAYOUT_CTE
)
```

Then I can just cross apply or outer apply to this table valued function to generate data based on input values.

If `COMP_NO` and `CUR_KEY` are values in a `"TEST"` table, I could use each of the rows with `COMP_NO` and `CUR_KEY` to run the CTE with those values and save them, like below:

```
SELECT PC.*
    INTO #PAYOUT_CTE_TMP
FROM TEST T
    CROSS APPLY TVFN_PAYOUT_CTE (T.COMP_NO, T.CUR_KEY) PC
```

By doing this, the CTE is rebuilt and ran for each row from the `TEST` table.

Comment: Nice use of UDF to get cte results. Thaks.

Comment: @GLSOFTINDIA If this worked, I'd really appreciate some upvotes or accepted answers.

Comment: @Radu Gheorghiu Late to arrive, but your answer was very helpful to me and I gave you my well-deserved upvote!

Comment: @DevinVyain glad it's still useful after so many years