# Conversion of CTE to temp table in SQL Server to get All Possible Parents

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, temp-tables

I have one user table in which I maintain parent child relationship and I want to generate the result with all user id along with its parentid and all possible hierarchical parents as comma separated strings.

My table structure is as follows.

```
CREATE TABLE [hybarmoney].[Users](
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,   
    [USERID] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [REFERENCEID] [bigint] NULL 
)
```

and I am getting the result using the below CTE

```
;WITH Hierarchy (
    ChildId
    ,ChildName
    ,ParentId
    ,Parents
    )
AS (
    SELECT Id
        ,USERID
        ,REFERENCEID
        ,CAST('' AS VARCHAR(MAX))
    FROM hybarmoney.Users AS FirtGeneration
    WHERE REFERENCEID = 0

    UNION ALL

    SELECT NextGeneration.ID
        ,NextGeneration.UserID
        ,Parent.ChildId
        ,CAST(CASE 
                WHEN Parent.Parents = ''
                    THEN (CAST(NextGeneration.REFERENCEID AS VARCHAR(MAX)))
                ELSE (Parent.Parents + ',' + CAST(NextGeneration.REFERENCEID AS VARCHAR(MAX)))
                END AS VARCHAR(MAX))
    FROM hybarmoney.Users AS NextGeneration
    INNER JOIN Hierarchy AS Parent ON NextGeneration.REFERENCEID = Parent.ChildId
    )
SELECT *
FROM Hierarchy
ORDER BY ChildId
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

[image: Result Obtained from Above CTE]

But I have the limitation of MAXRECURSION and when I googled, I got to know that temp tables are an alternative solution but I was not able to do the same 
and also i don't want to get all possible top parents, for my purpose I want to find 15 levels of hierarchical parents for each users. Is it possible to use temp tables for my purpose if possible how.

Comment: Do you have freedom to alter or augment your datamodel? If so, have you looked into Joe Celko's NSM architecture? I've had great success with it in similar hierarchical data schemes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do, in order to get only `N` levels of your CTE is to create an additional column where you keep track of each level.

```
;WITH Hierarchy (
    ChildId
    ,ChildName
    ,ParentId
    ,LEVEL
    ,Parents
    )
AS (
    SELECT Id
        ,USERID
        ,REFERENCEID
        ,0 AS LEVEL
        ,CAST('' AS VARCHAR(MAX))
    FROM hybarmoney.Users AS FirtGeneration
    WHERE REFERENCEID = 0

    UNION ALL

    SELECT NextGeneration.ID
        ,NextGeneration.UserID
        ,Parent.ChildId
        ,LEVEL+1 AS LEVEL
        ,CAST(CASE 
                WHEN Parent.Parents = ''
                    THEN (CAST(NextGeneration.REFERENCEID AS VARCHAR(MAX)))
                ELSE (Parent.Parents + ',' + CAST(NextGeneration.REFERENCEID AS VARCHAR(MAX)))
                END AS VARCHAR(MAX))
    FROM hybarmoney.Users AS NextGeneration
    INNER JOIN Hierarchy AS Parent ON NextGeneration.REFERENCEID = Parent.ChildId
    )
SELECT *
FROM Hierarchy
WHERE LEVEL <= 15
ORDER BY ChildId
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

This works, assuming I understood correctly your following statement: "for my purpose I want to find 15 levels of hierarchical parents for each users", where you actually meant 15 levels of hierarchical parents for **a single user** (in your case `REFERENCEID=0`).

If you want this to generate a list of 15 hierarchical parents **for each user** in your `hybarmoney.Users` table, then move your CTE in a table valued function and implement a similar solution as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48003428/create-cte-multiple-times-and-drop-cte/48003840#48003840).

Comment: the Levels and data is high it exceeds  ctes limit

Comment: @BaluSidhartha that's a *very good thing* because it prevents runaway loops that take forever and lock the entire table. If you have so many levels use `hierarchyid`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos is there any benefit of using `hierarchyid` over a regular `integer`?

Comment: A `hierarchyid` is essentially a path in binary form, eg `1\21\134\567` so searching for children of `21` means finding all rows that start with `1\21`. That's just a single range search. This results in orders of magnitude better performance and no recursion limits.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same result using the flowing query if there may be better solution

```
Create PROC UspUpdateUserAndFiftenLevelIDs (@UserID BIGINT)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @REFERENCEIDString NVARCHAR(max)

    SET @REFERENCEIDString = ''

    DECLARE @ReferenceID BIGINT

    SET @ReferenceID = @UserID

    DECLARE @Count INT

    SET @Count = 0

    WHILE (@count < 15)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @ReferenceID = U.REFERENCEID
            ,@REFERENCEIDString = @REFERENCEIDString + CASE 
                WHEN @REFERENCEIDString = ''
                    THEN (CAST(U.REFERENCEID AS VARCHAR(100)))
                ELSE (',' + CAST(U.REFERENCEID AS VARCHAR(MAX)))
                END
        FROM hybarmoney.Users U
        WHERE U.ID = @ReferenceID

        SET @Count = @Count + 1
    END
        SELECT @UserID
            ,@REFERENCEIDString


END
```

Comment: A better solution is to use a recursive CTE. Looping is the slowest possible way of working with data. If you have a bug with your original query, fix the bug. Don't throw it away

Comment: If you want to go down only 15 levels you should pass the level number to each recursion, the same way you pass `Parents` and increment it. Terminate the recursion whe you reach the maximum level

Comment: i could not use cte because the max recursion size exceeds

Comment: In that case use `hierarchyid`. Using `WHILE` is no solution - you'd still get a runaway recursion only you won't have the recursion limit to save you

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - unless there are people like I, who are switching to Fabric Data Warehouse, where main problem is: "Recursive CTEs are unsupported in this version of Synapse SQL." Apparently slow and robust makes a comeback...

Comment: @AcePL Fabric isn't SQL Server. It's not even a database, it's an umbrella marketing term. Whatever database it uses isn't the same as on-premise SQL Server or Azure SQL either. That slow WHILE was never robust, only slow, even back in 2000.

Comment: @AcePL in fact, if you move to Fabric or any similar data warehouse/lake/whatever architecture you'll need a *very* different schema and architecture from the OLTP data you may be trying to migrate. WHILE was never an option anyway, even back in 2000. The fast way back then was nested sets. In data warehouses though, dimensions rarely have arbitrary hierarchy levels. To get fast aggregations from a fact table you need to know the granularity of the measures - essentially the maximum nesting level

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - what I need i a simple SQL DB to host 20 tables, 15 SPs and 10 views. Fabric warehouse is the only way to go if using Fabric Capacity. Thus - see my previous comment